# Python: New Object loses array attributes

Tags: python, arrays, reference

I'm currently writing a python programm that should create an array of class objects, which a have created.

The problem I'm facing is, that the class has an array as attribute. After I do myArray.clear() the class object loses the array values. The other values doesn't get lost. I know this is due to the reference of the array, but I don't know how to fix this.

Code example:

**Class**

```
class Testclass(object):
   def __init__(self, array, normalValue):
    self._array= array
    self._normalValue= normalValue
```

**Main**

```
if __name__=="main":
   exampleIteratorArray = ["Ex1", "Ex2", "Ex3"]
   objectArray = []
   for i, value in enumerate(exampleIteratorArray):
         exampleArray = [i, i+1, i+2]
         objectArray.append(Testclass(exampleArray, value))
         exampleArray.clear()              #I have to do this because I want to check the state depending on the value of this variable (in my main code)
                                            #After the exampleArray.clear(), the objectArray loses the exampleArray values but not the i value
```

Therefore, I wanted to know how I can add objects to the array without losing the values after each iteration.
Thanks in advance! :)

**Edit**

As Azro pointed out, I create a new varaible from exampleArray every iteration therrefore I dont need to clear the array.

Comment: Why do use clear ? You empty the array, seems normal it's empty after

Comment: Just don't `clear`. Or do `self._array= list(array)` to copy

Comment: @azro I clear the array because in my main programm I appen values to the array but for the object I only want the values from the current iteration and because I append values I get the values from the ones before. Maybe there is a better way to do this ? But thanks your trick did the work!

Comment: You create `exampleArray` at each iteration, you do not append to it, so no problem, just remove the clear line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python, a list assignment refers to the same (original) instance of the list. When you clear the local array, you are clearing both the local array and the one you think you copied into the object (but actually didn’t), since these are in fact the same array.

Simple example:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = a
a.append(4)
print(b)
# prints [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

To assign / copy an array as a separate object, you need to use a copy or deep copy operation. A simple way in your current code would be a slice-to-copy:

```
objectArray.append(Testclass(exampleArray[:], value))
```

Note the `[:]` added.